# How to plot and get coordinates of two intersecting lines on graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a Python program that at the moment, just plots two lines. I want it to look something like the picture below the first picture but right now it looks like this.

[Image of Graph without Intersection Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G1py.png)

[Image of Graph with Intersection Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8hMQ.png)

My code that plots the graph is right here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = data.sort_values(['time'])
x = np.array(data['time'])
y = np.array(data['amount'])

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)

x_dense = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 500)
y_dense = np.interp(x_dense, x, y)

mask = y_dense < p(x_dense)
x_masked = np.ma.array(x_dense, mask=mask)

plt.title("Trend Time")
plt.plot(x_dense, p(x_dense), 'g-', lw=0.5)
plt.plot(x_masked, p(x_masked), 'r--', lw=2.25)
plt.fill_between(x_dense, p(x_dense), y_dense, where=~mask, color='crimson', alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

How can I plot those intersection points?

Comment: Since you're not having difficulty with the csv, could you modify this example so that we could run the code without your specific data. That is, it would be helpful if you'd convert it to an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use scatter to plot points in a chart:

```
plt.scatter(x_masked, p(x_masked), lw=4)
```